# Firebase Query for Products in Categories (database setup and best practice)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

***TL;DR***
products have multiple categories.
View should show only all subcategories and products that have the category assigned.

How to setup the DB and queries?

---

I'm learning Vue and Firebase at the moment coming from a C# and SQL background, I need some help and advice on the noSQL side of things.

**EDIT**: categories and products are two separate collections (at the moment).

I have products, which can have multiple categories (see product 5)

```
products: {
  prod1-id: {
    name:'apple-type-A',
    price: 2
    cats: cat1-id
  }
  prod2-id: {
    name:'apple-type-B',
    price: 2.5
    cats: cat1-id
  }
  prod3-id: {
    name:'banana-type-A',
    price: 1.6
    cats: cat2-id
  }
  prod4-id: {
    name:'banana-type-B',
    price: 1.9
    cats: cat2-id
  }
  prod5-id: {
    name:'smoothie',
    price: 5,
    cats: [cat2-id, subCat1-id, subCat2-id]
  }
}
```

Those categories are a tree.

```
categories: {
  cat1-id: {
    name: 'fruits',
    subCat1-id: {
      name: 'apple'
    }
    subCat2-id: {
      name: 'banana'
    }
  },
  cat2-id: {
    name: 'MySmooth'
  }
}
```

The customer should see the first tree.

The landing page should only show the first depth of the category tree and every product without a category (maybe add a category called 'no category').

When you click on a category is should show all the subcategories and products, that have this category.

This goes on until the deepest branch.

I tried to sketch my idea:

[image: Customer views]

---

***VIEW***

For programming I use Vue, with vuex and vuexfire and as framework Vuetify.

I have the complete product management setup but I don't know how to query for this view.

My idea was to reuse a `<v-card v-for="p of products">` I already have and is working fine.

But this shows only products, not categories. How do I get the categories into the mix?

**QUERY**

Working with vuexfire this is quite simple.

```
bindSoldProducts: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }) => bindFirestoreRef('products', productsColl.where('isSold', '==', true))
```

but how can I get the categories and products now show side by side?

I've started to get the products together by querying, but have no idea how to put the categories into the mix:

```
firebase.firestore.collection('products').orderBy('name', 'asc').onSnapshot(snap => {
  const productsArray: any = []

  snap.forEach(doc => {
    const product = doc.data()
    product.id = doc.id
    productsArray.push(product)
  })

  store.commit('setAllProducts', productsArray)
})
```

Do I need to structure my database differently?

Do I just query the products and use "some js logic/magic" to show the categories? But how would I then get the views.

Are the collection group queries of firebase the right way to go? If yes, how?

Please advice

Comment: Without going to deep, I see one issue immediately. `[cat2-id, subCat1-id, subCat2-id]` you're mixing two different 'things' in one array. How would you distinguish one from the other (a cat vs a subCat)?

Comment: @Jay nono, i should have named them "cat3" and "cat4". I just wanted to explain, that categories can be in categories themselves like products.

Comment: I would suggest re-thinking how the question is being asked. You've gotten comments and a couple of answers that don't seem to go along with the question. Shorten and clarify it and then we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay, I know, but everything here helped a bit so far. currently I have a solution, when I got the subscription ready I'll post it here

Answer (score 0):

Try a for in all Categories and get the fruits:

```
const categories = {
 "cat1-id": []
}

Object.keys(categories).forEach(cat => {
   const res = db.collection('products').where('cats', 'array-contains', cat).get()
   // Resolve and put (push) in categories[cat]
})
```

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Will this still maintain realtime updates, when something like inventory changes?

Comment: Using the get method you will not see changes, define the variable categories at the top and start to observe the changes and assign them within the variable in the same way

Comment: Ok, this works in getting the products, but how do i get products and sub-categories?
Do i have to run queries for both and join everything in one array, so i can show it's contents?

Comment: from what I understand of your data structure, "cats" within "products" is an array that includes categories and subcategories, so the query applies to categories and subcategories.
It is up to you to create a variable for the categories and subcategories.
It can be very heavy in your application if you are going to observe everything, so I recommend using good practices to observe only what the user needs

Comment: Maybe we have a different understanding here: 'Categories' are one collection and 'products' are a separate collection. I have made references in my products to the categories. The tree structure is only in the 'category-collection'.
I'll try a bit and edit my post later on what i found out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing my response an answer as it was too long for a comment.

If I understood your use case correctly, you want to have a DB structure where you have a list of products and their respective categories which both will be displayed simultaneously side by side on your Vue application view.

While I'm not a Vue expert, I can suggest using the following structure for your Cloud Firestore database: *Products/{product}/categories/{category}*, which translates to *collection/{document}/collection/{document}*.

In the [Cloud Firestore data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) you can have a collection within another collection, and this is called a subcollection. For example, you could have *Products/fruits/Categories/banana* and inside the *banana* document you could have *type*, *price*, or *id* fields among many others.

Then, you could use [Collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to retrieve documents from a collection group instead of from a single collection. A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID. By default, queries retrieve results from a single collection in your database.

For example, you could create a *categories* collection group by adding a *Categories* subcollection to each *product* and then retrieve results from every product's categories subcollection at once, let's say *bananas*:

```
const querySnapshot = await db.collectionGroup('categories').where('productName', '==', 'banana').get();
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  // Banana from Mexico, Banana from Honduras, etc.
});
```

Before using a collection group query, do not forget to create [an index that supports your collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing). You can create an index through an error message, the console, or the Firebase CLI.

Comment: No sorry, wrong.
I'll edit my question and try to explain it better:
collection 1: products
collection 2: categories