# Vue, firestore: how to display LIVE data after merging collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

**See EDIT Below**

---

I have massively improved over [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772182), but I am stuck again after some days of work.

Using Vue, Vue-router, Vuex and Vuetify with the Data on Googles Could Firestore

I want to update my data live, but i cannot find a way to do this.
Do i need to restructure, like moving products and categories into one collection?
Or is there any *bind or query magic* to get this done.
As you can see below, **it loads the data on click quite well, but I need the live binding** 'cause you could have the page open and someone could sell the last piece (amountLeft = 0). (And a lot of future ideas).

My data structure is the following:

```
categories: {
  cat_food: {
    name: 'Food'
    parentCat: 'nC'
  },
  cat_drinks: {
    name: 'Food'
    parentCat: 'nC'
  },
  cat_beer: {
    name: 'Beer'
    parentCat: 'cat_drinks'
  },
  cat_spritz: {
    name: 'Spritzer'
    parentCat: 'cat_drinks'
  },
}

products: {
  prod_mara: {
    name: 'Maracuja Spritzer'
    price: 1.5
    amountLeft: 9
    cat: ['cat_spritz']
  },
  prod_capp: {
    name: 'Cappuccino'
    price: 2
    cat: ['cat_drinks']
  },
}
```

The categories and the products build a tree. The GIF shows me opening the categories down to show a product. You see that it's a product when you have a price tag.
You can see there are two categories that have the same parent (cat_drinks).
The product *prod_capp* is also assigned to the category and shown side by side to the categories.

[image: Opening categories]

I get the data currently this way:

**catsOrProd.js**

```js
import { catsColl, productsColl } from '../firebase'

const state = {
  catOrProducts: [],
}

const mutations = {
  setCats(state, val) {
    state.catOrProducts = val
  }
}

const actions = {
  // https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuexfire.html#firestoreaction

  async bindCatsWithProducts({ commit, dispatch }, CatID) {
    if (CatID) {
      // console.log('if CatID: ', CatID)
      await Promise.all([
        catsColl.where('parentCat', '==', CatID).orderBy('name', 'asc').get(),
        productsColl.where('cats', 'array-contains', CatID).orderBy('name', 'asc').get()
      ])
        .then(snap => dispatch('moveCatToArray', snap))
    } else {
      // console.log('else CatID: ', CatID)
      await Promise.all([
        catsColl.where('parentCat', '==', 'nC').orderBy('name', 'asc').get(),
        productsColl.where('cats', 'array-contains', 'nC').orderBy('name', 'asc').get()
      ])
        .then(snap => dispatch('moveCatToArray', snap))
    }
  },

  async moveCatToArray({ commit }, snap) {
    const catsArray = []
    // console.log(snap)
    await Promise.all([
      snap[0].forEach(cat => {
        catsArray.push({ id: cat.id, ...cat.data() })
      }),
      snap[1].forEach(cat => {
        catsArray.push({ id: cat.id, ...cat.data() })
      })
    ])
      .then(() => commit('setCats', catsArray))
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
}
```

This is a part of my vue file that is showing the data on screen. I have left out the unnecessary parts.
To open everything a have a route with props and clicking on the category sends the router to the next category. (this way i can move back with browser functionality).
**Sale.vue**

```js
<template>
...........
<v-col
  v-for="catOrProduct in catOrProducts"
  :key="catOrProduct.id"
  @click.prevent="leftClickProd($event, catOrProduct)"
  @contextmenu.prevent="rightClickProd($event, catOrProduct)">

....ViewMagic....
</v-col>
............
</template>

<script>
.........
  props: {
    catIdFromUrl: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined
    }
  },

  computed: {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322404/vuejs-how-can-i-use-computed-property-with-v-for
    ...mapState('catOrProducts', ['catOrProducts']),
  },

  watch: {
    '$route.path'() { this.bindCatsWithProducts(this.catIdFromUrl) },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.bindCatsWithProducts(this.catIdFromUrl)
  },

  methods: {
    leftClickProd(event, catOrProd) {
      event.preventDefault()
      if (typeof (catOrProd.parentCat) === 'string') { // when parentCat exists we have a Category entry
        this.$router.push({ name: 'sale', params: { catIdFromUrl: catOrProd.id } })
        // this.bindCatsWithProducts(catOrProd.id)
      } else {
        // ToDo: Replace with buying-routine
        this.$refs.ProductMenu.open(catOrProd, event.clientX, event.clientY)
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

---

**EDIT 24.09.2020**

I have changed my binding logic to

```
const mutations = {
  setCatProd(state, val) {
    state.catOrProducts = val
  },
}

const actions = {
async bindCatsWithProducts({ commit, dispatch }, CatID) {
    const contain = CatID || 'nC'
    const arr = []

    catsColl.where('parentCat', '==', contain).orderBy('name', 'asc')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        snap.forEach(cat => {
          arr.push({ id: cat.id, ...cat.data() })
        })
      })

    productsColl.where('cats', 'array-contains', contain).orderBy('name', 'asc')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        snap.forEach(prod => {
          arr.push({ id: prod.id, ...prod.data() })
        })
      })

    commit('setCatProd', arr)
  },
}
```

This works, as the data gets updated when I change something in the backend.

But now i get an object added everytime something changes. As example i've changed the price. Now i get this:
[image: Two products with identical ID's]

I don't know why, because i have the `key` field set in Vue. The code for the rendering is:

```html
<v-container fluid>
  <v-row
    align="center"
    justify="center"
  >
    <v-col
      v-for="catOrProduct in catOrProducts"
      :key="catOrProduct.id"
      @click.prevent="leftClickProd($event, catOrProduct)"
      @contextmenu.prevent="rightClickProd($event, catOrProduct)"
    >
      <div>
        <TileCat
          v-if="typeof(catOrProduct.parentCat) == 'string'"
          :src="catOrProduct.pictureURL"
          :name="catOrProduct.name"
        />
        <TileProduct
          v-if="catOrProduct.isSold"
          :name="catOrProduct.name"
          ... other props...
        />
      </div>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

Why is this not updating correctly?

Comment: So what is your actual question again?

Comment: Do I understand right, that you always want to have an up to date amount of available products?

Comment: At the moment, your code is very imperative, check these docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen This allows you to value changes (in firestore) and then re-set your store data.

Comment: @Tallboy: How to get live Updates.

Comment: @sandrooco exactly this, and some other fields. so you think just going for the onSnapshot works here?

Comment: Yes that's probably the easiest solution. It's unlikely that you can just change from `.get()` to `.onSnapshot` - but I think you can handle a few line changes. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the Vuefire [docs](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/), this is how you would subscribe to changes with Firebase only:

```vue
// get Firestore database instance
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const db = firebase.initializeApp({ projectId: 'MY PROJECT ID' }).firestore()

new Vue({
  // setup the reactive todos property
  data: () => ({ todos: [] }),

  created() {
    // unsubscribe can be called to stop listening for changes
    const unsubscribe = db.collection('todos').onSnapshot(ref => {
      ref.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        const { newIndex, oldIndex, doc, type } = change
        if (type === 'added') {
          this.todos.splice(newIndex, 0, doc.data())
          // if we want to handle references we would do it here
        } else if (type === 'modified') {
          // remove the old one first
          this.todos.splice(oldIndex, 1)
          // if we want to handle references we would have to unsubscribe
          // from old references' listeners and subscribe to the new ones
          this.todos.splice(newIndex, 0, doc.data())
        } else if (type === 'removed') {
          this.todos.splice(oldIndex, 1)
          // if we want to handle references we need to unsubscribe
          // from old references
        }
      })
    }, onErrorHandler)
  },
})
```

I would generally avoid any unnecessary dependencies, but according to your objectives, you can use Vuefire to add another layer of abstraction, or as you said, doing some *"magic binding"*.

```vue
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const db = firebase.initializeApp({ projectId: 'MY PROJECT ID' }).firestore()

new Vue({
  // setup the reactive todos property
  data: () => ({ todos: [] }),
  firestore: {
    todos: db.collection('todos'),
  },
})
```

Comment: this would only subscribe to *one* collection. My problem are the two collections at the same time in one array. You can clearly see this in the question, when I call prodColl.get() and catchall.get()

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, you are definitely right. Before I edit my question, I would like to note that when you have every element of an array being shown `v-for="catOrProduct in catOrProducts"`, Vue [won't display](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) a reactive array even when the binding works properly. You will have to setup a `watcher` or do `$forceUpdate()` to ensure that your data is up to date. Don't rely on what is displayed on screen before this is fixed. Rely on your [DevTools extension](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) to see live updates.